# Block chrome://extensions

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to block `chrome://extensions` page? I have some good productivity extensions but it's no use if I can disable them.

Is there a way to block it with a password or something?

Comment: Yes and no. It's possible with the ["for Business" version of the browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/), but it's massively inconvenient, and all the same problems apply (you turn on certain features... so you have access to turn them off).

Comment: Wow, it actually occurred to Google to consider offices‽ I am **shocked**! In my experience, the Google devs have been blind to any use-cases different from what they personally use, and don’t understand, know, or care about what others want or how they use computers.